# Delete operation is forbidden for current area magento 2

Tags: magento2

I added some custom attributes and i 
set 
- **show_address_fields**  -> true in the layout for the reference block **customer_form_register** but i get this error when trying to create a customer. The address is not added but the customer is added so what's the problem. Any help ,please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your construct function add the Registry class like -

```
\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
```

And then in your construct function add like -

```
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
```

Comment: Which construct i need to add this i am getting same error on create customer in magento2 ?

Comment: I have the same issue, can you add some more reference to this solution? Would be supergreat!

Comment: I have the same problem, may I ask which constructor ? Registry is now deprecated